# How to provide input of a text file to a query in shell

Tags: shell, grep

I was writing a shell script and stuck in a place. I have a input file where I have two columns first column has a log file name and second has the line number of first occurrence of a syntax. example as below.

file name: checkit.txt

contents

```
hellohowru.log 12345
helpmehere.log 45677
checkitout.log 67543
```

I want to grep for a particular syntax or word in each log file inside the txt file checkit.txt starting from line number in its respective row.

How can I loop it for all log files.

for eg: `tail -n +12345 hellohowru.log| grep -il 'exception'` 
if exception is found I can have the file name.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a `while read` loop:

```
while read -r file num; do
    tail -n +$num "$file" | grep -qi 'exception' && echo "$file"
done < checkit.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { ARGV[ARGC]=$1; ARGC++; start[$1]=$2; next }
    (FNR > start[FILENAME]) && (tolower($0) ~ /exception/) { print FILENAME; nextfile }
' checkit.txt
```

The above uses GNU awk for `nextfile` and handling of any number of open files - if you don't have gawk then in any awk it'd be:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { ARGV[ARGC]=$1; ARGC++; start[$1]=$2; next }
    FNR==1  { close(prev); prev=FILENAME }
    (FNR > start[FILENAME]) && (tolower($0) ~ /exception/) && !seen[FILENAME]++ { print FILENAME }
' checkit.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

another simple solution

Algo:
- Read through file line-by-line
- Get the filename and linenume
- Execute tail + grep command for "exception"
- If match found, print the filename

```
cat checkit.txt | while read line
do
    LOGFILE=$(echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
    LINECNT=$(echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}')
    #echo "HI : $LOGFILE and $LINECNT"

    tail -n +$LINECNT $LOGFILE | grep -i "exception" 1> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0  ]
    then
        echo "EXCEPTION IN $LOGFILE"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You have at least half a dozen shell scripting mistakes in that script. Let me know if you'd like to hear about them.

Comment: At a glance: 1) UUOC 2) Incorrect `while read` syntax 3) Use of upper case names for non-exported variables 4) Needlessly setting the awk FS to it's default value. 5) Not quoting shell variables 6) Wrong file descriptor on grep output redirection 7) Redirecting grep output instead of using the grep arg to not produce output. 8) reading the whole line then splitting it instead of splitting it while reading. Let me know if there's any of those you don't understand and would like more info about.

Comment: thanks for your response. I should take care. btw (6,7) were intentional: I didn't want o/p to be printed as user didn't ask for it. I didn't understand UUOC; my bad. and also I don't understand why `while read` syntax in incorrect?

Comment: For 6 I should have said "unnecessary" instead of "wrong" as `1` is the default FD for `cmd >whatever`. For 7, just use `grep -q` and it won't produce output, no need to have grep produce output and then redirect it to /dev/null. UUOC means "Useless Use Of Cat" which along with not quoting variables are by far THE most common shell scripting mistakes. Google UUOC. When you want to read lines from a file as-is, you need to use `while IFS= read -r line`. Otherwise, what you get in your variable may not be what was in the file so do it cautiously only when necessary to fulfill an objective.

Comment: You're welcome. See @anubhava's answer for how to write it in shell without the problems I listed as 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 8 (4 and 6 are not applicable to his script since solving 7 and 8 removes the need for the lines that had those problems). The shell is NOT designed to manipulate text, it's designed to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools - that's why it's SO difficult to write a shell script correctly to manipulate text. For text manipulation, just use awk - it's what it was designed for and so does easily, intuitively, and efficiently (MUCH faster than shell loops!)